# Why is spring data neo4j making large number of http calls to get related nodes

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Why is SDN making a large number of http calls to fetch the related graph having defined @Fetch attribute on the fields. Seems like no eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

For historic reasons SDN up to 3.2.2 heavily uses core Neo4j API calls. While this is fast for embedded it slows down when connected via REST.

The following blog post explains this in regards to history and future of SDN: [Spring Data Neo4j 3.3.0 – Improving Remoting Performance](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/12/spring-data-neo4j-improving-remoting-performance/).

Apart from the SDN 3.3.0 performance gains there is also a rewritten SDN in the works that specifically focusses on Neo4j over REST via Cypher: [SDN4 / neo4j-ogm](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm).